# Using Ubuntu Live CD to create disk image?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, backup, disk-image

My Windows laptop (ThinkPad W520) has issues. Windows cannot repair itself. I have used a USB adapter to verify that the HDD is fine and also managed to boot it up using an Ubuntu Live disk. I want to create an explorable image of my HDD before I wipe it clean and install windows 7 on it again.

I want to know if it's possible to utilize this Ubuntu live disk and make an image of my laptop's HDD and save it onto my external hard drive? I want to create an image which I will be able to browse from my new windows installation on my laptop.

Is this doable?

Comment: Yes this is possible to do from the live cd I would also look here ( http://clonezilla.org/)

Comment: would you happen to know how? (checking out CloneZilla now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot your Ubuntu live system and connect the external HDD where you want to save the image. You do not need to (or should not?) mount the Windows HDD.

Open `gnome-disks` by searching for it in the Dash's application lens (<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>), entering it into the HUD (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) or launching it from a terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).

When the window below opens, select your source drive on the left (the 250GB Hitachi HDD in my example, see red circle). Then open the drive context menu by clicking on the hamburger button on the right (see red arrow).

[image: > Screenshot: gnome-disks]

[image: > Screenshot: gnome-disks - disk context menu]

In the appearing context menu above, select <kbd>**Create Disk Image...**</kbd> to open another dialogue window:

[image: > Screenshot: gnome-disks - disk image dialogue]

Enter a nice file name for the disk image file to create and select a location (the external HDD) where to save it. Be careful that the target directory is **not** on the source disk!

Then click the <kbd>**Start Creating...**</kbd> button, lean back and get yourself cup of a coffee.
Repeat the last action (coffee) until the process has finished. ;-D

Comment: WOW! That was a detailed and helpful answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm happy that I could support you.